# How to loop an Object in GNUmakefile

Tags: gnu-make

I am new to GNUmakefile and what I want to do is really simple. As you can see below, OBJS contains all the *.c files under MYDir . What I want to do next is to have a program called MyProgram to run on EACH .c file stored in the OBJS . But I don’t know how to pass each .c from the OBJS to “runThis”.

Thanks

```
DIR := MyDir
OBJS := $(wildcard $(DIR:=/*.c))

.PHONY: all

all : $(OBJS) runThis

runThis:
        MyProgram   some.c
```

Comment: There's not enough information in your question to answer it.  Make is used to convert one type of file into another type of file.  Here you say you are running `MyProgram` on each source file, but you don't say what the output of `MyProgram` will be.  Until you specify that, you can't write your makefile (and we can't help you).

Comment: Make allows you to write rules about how to create things based on dependencies. Your `all` rule depends on `$(OBJS)` (`OBJ` should perhaps be named `CFILES` or something similar instead to not cause confusion). There is no rule to make `$(OBJS)`. As `$(OBJS)` is created using `$(wildcard)` based on files existing in directory, it has no function (not even in giving you an error if you file does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

Most simply, you could pass the  `$(OBJS)` (which I took the liberty of renaming to CFILES) directly in the rule:

```
DIR := MyDir
CFILES := $(wildcard $(DIR:=/*.c))

.PHONY: all

all:
        for f in $(CFILES); do MyProg $$f; done
```

This is assuming Bourne style shell (like `bash`, `dash`, `ash`, etc) and that your file names do not contain spaces.

You could also let the GNU make do the "hard work" of looping:

```
DIR := MyDir
CFILES := $(wildcard $(DIR:=/*.c))

.PHONY: all

define gen-rule
  all: process-$1

  process-$1:
        MyProg $1

endef

$(eval $(foreach c,$(CFILES),$(call gen-rule,$(c))))
```

For each file `$(c)` in `$(CFILES)`, we create a rule `process-$(c)` and induce `all` rule to depend on that rule.

Answer (score 0):

Hear's another route:

```
DIR := MyDir
OBJS := $(wildcard $(DIR:=/*.c))

DUMMY_TGTS := $(addsuffix ., $(OBJS))

.PHONY: all $(DUMMY_TGTS)

all : $(DUMMY_TGTS)

$(DUMMY_TGTS) : %. : %
    MyProgram $<
```

As usual with stackoverflow make answers you will need to switch the indent from spaces to a tab.

It uses a [Static Pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Static-Pattern.html#Static-Pattern) to call `MyProgram` on each of the `.c` files individually. The `DUMMY_TGTS` are setup with `.PHONY`ensure they will still trigger the rule even if there is a file existing with that name.